# Skype-call-recorder keeps showing up legal information

Tags: skype

I've installed skype-call-recorder. On first call, legal information window popped up notifying me about legal stuff.
I checked dont show again option. However, every time I restart PC, it shows again.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is easy.
Just edit `~/.skypecallrecorder.rc`.
Change

```
suppress.legalinformation = no
```

to

```
suppress.legalinformation = yes
```